# Android, GoogleMaps: how to pass address to Res

Tags: java, android, xml, google-maps

I have a text variable in my java code, whose value is a location address.
I'd like to write this address into a text box, placed in the Res folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    tools:context="com.example.currentplacedetailsonmap.MapsActivityCurrentPlace" />
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/text_box"
    android:inputType="text"/>
```

So, does it exist a java coded method, by which I can achieve this target?

Thank you very much.

Comment: From where you are getting the location? From the marker?

Comment: @tahsinRupam :-)

Comment: What ?? @nihal_softy

Comment: I catch the address from Lat and Lng and then convert to a string:   StringBuilder strAddress = new StringBuilder();  <...get the address...>; String completed = strAddress.toString();   now I want to insert the value of the string variable "completed" into the edittext built up in XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Enable Edittext use this

```
android:enabled="false"
```

and in your java code simley `edittext.setText("Your Data");`

**Use TextView instead of Edittext** (if you want to display only)